# Python command line loading bar

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line, command-line-interface

I have seen a few different loading bars that are displayed in the terminal. However, some of them rely on `\r` which does not seem to work, and it may be because I use Python 2.7 rather than 3.X.

I have got a loading bar, but it prints a new line each time.

```
def update_progress(progress):
    print"\r [{0}] {1}%".format('#'*(progress/10), progress)

while prog != 101:
    update_progress(prog)
    prog = prog + 1`
```

I am very new to Python so if you can make the code short and understandable if possible. This post may look like a duplicate question, but some others on Stack Overflow do not work or print on new lines.

If `\r` is supposed to work on Python 2.7 then could you explain how to fix it as it does not work? However, this confuses me as `\n` works perfectly fine but that is another issue.

P.S: I also need it to clear the line before printing again.

Thanks
AlwaysAwake

Comment: this has nothing to do with python, and everything to do with the terminal you're outputting this text to. python couldn't care less if you're outputting a `\r` or the text of War & Peace. It's just a sequence of characters to spit out - how those characters are interpreted is up to the terminal, not python.

Comment: @MarcB One issue is that OP's `print` prints a newline, which has to do with Python.

Comment: I know but in IDLE (default terminal) the \r does nothing and prints a space instead.

Comment: Be careful with `'#'*(progress/10)`, in Python 3 you can't "multiply" a string by a float, but I don't know the behavior in Python 2. Use `//` if you want the result of your division to be an integer.

Comment: @Aurel it works in Python2, but nice catch nonetheless

Comment: This is very terminal dependent, too. Most terminals will display `-\r|` and `|` the same way, but it's perfectly reasonable for a fancy terminal to display a `|` superimposed over a `-`, because `\r` means move the cursor to the beginning of the line, not clear the line. Also, `foobarbaz\rhello` would usually display as `hellorbaz`, since the string preceding the carriage return is longer than the string following it. If you *really* mean to clear the line, then use `\r\e[2K` (assuming a terminal that conforms to the ANSI standard).

Comment: tqdm is a greate module for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the fact that you never initialize `prog` (I suppose you want
`prog = 0` before the `while` loop) you can suppress the printing of a newline-character in Python2 by putting a comma after the statement:

```
def update_progress(progress):
    print "\r [{0}] {1}%".format('#'*(progress//10), progress),
```

However, that comma is hard to miss when reading the code, so importing and using the Python 3 `print` function is better.

```
from __future__ import print_function

def update_progress(progress):
    print("\r [{0}] {1}%".format('#'*(progress//10), progress), end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `sys.stdout.write()` because `print()` adds a new line:

```
import sys
def update_progress(progress):
    sys.stdout.write("\r [{0}] {1}%".format('#'*(progress/10), progress))

while prog != 101:
    update_progress(prog)
    prog = prog + 1
```

Also, note that in python3, you can use the argument `end` with `print()`:

```
 print("\r [{0}] {1}%".format('#'*(progress/10), progress), end='')
```

Comment: Again that works but doesn't clear the line beforehand

Answer (score 0):

Please use `sys.stdout.write("yourstring")` and after that `sys.stdout.flush()` to make sure the content is displayed. For doing graphical things in cross-platform development, I would suggest you the Python libraries `termcolor` and `colorama`. They will color the windows command line so that you can make *beautiful* progress bars. If you want to publish your project you could just implement the codes of `colorama` and `termcolor` into your code, and you have a single file.

Have fun with Python

Famecastle